# Unable to access windows server via ssh key launch method (Jenkins)

Tags: linux, windows, jenkins, ssh, server

I installed jenkins on linux server and now i am creating jenkins_agent to connect with windows server. i am using launch method (Launch agent via ssh). Even i created ssh key pairs on linux server and i copied public key and paste it into windows server's authorized_keys file. I put in jenkins agent's credentials private key. all the configuration i have done that i found on internet. I am facing given below error.

```
SSHLauncher{host='ec2-54-87-91-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com', port=22, credentialsId='windows_jenkins_agent', jvmOptions='', javaPath='', prefixStartSlaveCmd='', suffixStartSlaveCmd='', launchTimeoutSeconds=60, maxNumRetries=10, retryWaitTime=15, sshHostKeyVerificationStrategy=hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.KnownHostsFileKeyVerificationStrategy, tcpNoDelay=true, trackCredentials=true}
[07/26/23 04:40:22] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ec2-54-87-91-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22.
Searching for ec2-54-87-91-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
Searching for ec2-54-87-91-21.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts
[07/26/23 04:40:22] [SSH] SSH host key matches key in Known Hosts file. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for Administrator_cred (credentialId:windows_jenkins_agent/method:publickey)
[07/26/23 04:40:23] [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
[07/26/23 04:40:23] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/26/23 04:40:23] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

please help anyone?

Jenkins installed on Linux Server.
SSH key pair already done on linux server.
via command line i am able to access linux server through private key from windows server.
via command line unable to access windows server through ssh , but it's working with password only.
If i am on linux server then i am unable to access windows server via ssh key. It's working only with password way.
That's why windows_agent unable to connect with windows server.
Jenkins Agent unable to connect with windows server via ssh key launch method.